# Watermark Textbox Interferes with Password Recovery Control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In both the loginview control and the password recovery control asp.net requires a textbox with the id "Username" to exist.  The problem is I am making the username textbox in the loginview control a watermarked one using the code below.  Unfortunately as soon as I do this the Password Recovery tool stops working.  The submit button simply does nothing.  Is there a way to reference the textbox's differently or something?

The loginview control is on a masterpage, the password recovery control is on one of the content pages.

```
<script src="script/WaterMark.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=UserName], [id*=Password]").WaterMark();

    });
</script>
```

Here is the watermark.min.js script:

```
eval(function (p, a, c, k, e, d) { e = function (c) { return c }; if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) { while (c--) { d[c] = k[c] || c } k = [function (e) { return d[e] } ]; e = function () { return '\\w+' }; c = 1 }; while (c--) { if (k[c]) { p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + e(c) + '\\b', 'g'), k[c]) } } return p } ('(4($){$.35.36=4(6){3 16={18:\'#37\'};3 6=$.34(16,6);17 15.39(4(){3 1=$(15);5(1.32==0)17;3 22=1.9("14");1.7("14");3 2;5(1.9("19")!="47"){2=1.49(46);2.7("40").7("48")}45{2=$("<44 19 = \'41\' />");2[0].20=1[0].20;2[0].13.11=1[0].13.11}2.9("21","21");2.8({42:6.18});2.29(22);1.43(2);5(1[0].30!=2[0].30){2.8({\'28-27\':\'23-24\'});1.8({\'28-27\':\'23-24\'})}1.10();2.26(4(){2.10();1.25();1.26()});1.38("31",4(){5(12.33(1.29())==""){1.10();2.25()}})})}})(12);', 10, 50, '|textBox|dummy|var|function|if|options|removeAttr|css|attr|hide|cssText|jQuery|style|title|this|defaults|return|WaterMarkTextColor|type|className|readonly|watermarkText|sans|serif|show|focus|family|font|val|offsetWidth|blur|length|trim|extend|fn|WaterMark|afafaf|bind|each|Id|text|color|after|input|else|true|password|name|clone'.split('|'), 0, {}))
```

Comment: Where did you get that watermark script? Is there any documentation there?

Comment: Hi @hans, unfortunately I cannot remember where the script came from.  So no documentation.

Comment: @Hans, I got it from [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Watermark-Text-for-ASPNet-TextBox-Password-and-MultiLine-TextArea-using-jQuery-Plugin.aspx)

Comment: It seems like you used it correctly (pity it uses the `title` attribute instead of html5's `placeholder`). Maybe check the javascript console for any javascript errors.

Comment: @Hans, I have checked the javascript console - no errors.  I have also noticed that if I set the password recovery console to template and remove the required field validator for the username textbox it works.  Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by referring to the full element id:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ctl00_LoginView3_Login3_UserName, #ctl00_LoginView3_Login3_Password").WaterMark();

    });
</script>
```

Comment: change your control to StaticName to reduce the name. So the name specified into asp control id will be used!

Comment: @Fals, I'm not sure what you mean, I cannot change the ID of the control that is the problem, both the login control and the password recovery control expect the id to be "username".  Do I misunderstand you?

Comment: If you create a custom template, you can change anything you want!

Comment: @Fals, Not sure what you mean, I have converted the username to a template,  but changing the id gives: `Login1: LayoutTemplate does not contain an IEditableTextControl with ID UserName for the username.`

Comment: Sorry! I wrote this comment in the wrong place! I said above that if you are using ASP.NET 4.0 or greater theres a propertie ClientIDMode, where you can set as Static. Then every html control generated will get a static ID as the same as the asp. Much more pretty than "ctl00_LoginView3_Login3_UserName" for exemple :)!

Comment: @Fals, yes I know of that property, but I don't think you understand the problem. If you set the ClientIdMode in the watermark textbox in the login control to static then the id of the textbox will become: "username".  Which means it is not distinguishable from the password recovery control which also has the textbox id: "username".  That means the script will prevent the password recovery control's submit button from functioning correctly.